# Getting a grapefruit tree to bear fruit in Phoenix, AZ?

Tags: citrus

We planted a grapefruit tree in our yard about 3 years ago. It was probably about 2 feet at the time. It is now about 6 feet and looks healthy, gets plenty of water and hubby has fertilized it some, but it has not flowered or bore any fruit. We are obviously not gardeners! But we would like to bring this tree to fruit-bearing. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to give it time. 3 years would be very early to bear. I know some of the nursery catalogs out there claim you'll get fruit that fast, but in my experience, their windows are usually a tad (or a lot) optimistic. The wait is hard, but there really isn't much you can do. The tree will flower when it is old enough and mature enough.

This is year 6 waiting for a pair of plum trees in my yard to bear. Last year I got 3 fruit which fell off before they were mature. I am hopeful that this will finally be my year. The nursery I got them from claimed I'd have fruit in 3 or 4 years.